# How disable dm-verity on Android Devices without using ADB?

Tags: android, kernel, adb, android-source

I'm building AOSP from source code, and I want to be able to flash a Google Apps package onto the ROM. However, when the phone reboots, the google apps are not applied, and someone has said that it might be because of DM-Verity.

I want to know how to disable this DM-Verity protection, which should be able to be disabled in the kernel source code. How can I get started on doing this?

I know there is an ADB command "adb disable-verity" which works, but I want my build to have dm-verity disabled by default.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: What target are you building for? Please let me know if you try what I've suggested.

Comment: Sorry I won't be at my PC for today, but I'll get around to trying it tomorrow. I'm build for the Nexus 5X. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand from AOSP makefiles, DM-Verity is enabled by device's partition at build time.

So, for example, if you plan to disable it for System partition you need to find `PRODUCT_SYSTEM_VERITY_PARTITION` macro inside your target Makefiles, remove/comment it and then build again.

The exact location can vary since Makefile hierarchy is kind of customizable, but I found it inside `device.mk` for [Huawei target on AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/device/huawei/angler/+/oreo-r6-release/device.mk#584) repo.

**EDIT:**

Another possibility is to disable DM-verity at all on `verity.mk` located [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/oreo-r6-release/target/product/verity.mk#17), but you need to test if disabling it triggers other errors during the build.

Comment: So I commented out the 3 lines after "setup dm-verity configs" in my device.mk and in verity.mk I set  PRODUCT_SUPPORTS_VERITY := false. Should that do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for your awesome help! I edited that, flashed Gapps and they were applied. However, when I open Google Play Store it says Play Services has stopped and gets stuck at checking info, but I think this is because I'm on Oreo and I found a beta, unofficial build of OpenGapps Pico which probably still has issues, so I don't think this is the problem anymore. Where do you learn stuff like this haha.

Comment: I'm glad to help! I'm also a bit surprised it worked on the first try! All that I did was search inside AOSP code for a few keywords and then try to follow some logic. BTW, I think this is the best way of learning about AOSP.

Comment: I should try that more, currently my first resource is Google :) Anyways thanks for all your help! :D Would you happen to know anything about getting my own custom vendor folder setup for overlays? I know Cyanogenmod has a vendor/cm and ParanoidAndroid has vendor/pa, and I'm looking to make my own like that for overlays and other stuff. Thx :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your full comment on that date. Are you still looking for that? I remember seeing some examples while working with AOSP, but I would need to read more about that before giving you an answer.

Comment: If it's possible for you it would be super helpful to get some info on vendor folders / making one and stuff :) Thanks!

Comment: +Perazzo any chance you were able to get some info? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @NateDev, I'm kinda busy since mid-Setempber and I couldn't study about it. I've just found a link that says something at slide 19th, take a look: https://elinux.org/images/2/29/Customizing_AOSP_for_my_Device.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this slide deck :)

Answer (score 0):

PS: Verity is disabled for eng builds.

`lunch <target>_eng` should work.

Or else, to disable verity, just use this:

Check in one of the make files: Example: `base.mk`
And do something like this:

```
# Disable Verity
PRODUCT_SYSTEM_VERITY_PARTITION :=
PRODUCT_VENDOR_VERITY_PARTITION :=
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := $(strip $(filter-out %verity.mk, $(PRODUCT_PACKAGES)))
```